Xcode: "Waiting to reconnect to Apple Watch" — Unable to proceed with watchOS app debugging
I'm working on an app that connects between an iOS app and an Apple Watch, using HealthKit to send heartbeat data from the watch to the iOS app via WatchKit. Both the mobile and watch apps are supposed to run in the background.
However, when I try to debug the Apple Watch part of the app, I keep encountering this issue in Xcode:
A dialog pops up saying "Waiting to reconnect to Apple Watch", and the debugger stalls until the connection is restored. I waited hours but gain
Here's the exact error message:
Referenece Image
I've tried the following, but the issue persists:
Restarting both Xcode and my Apple Watch.
Unpairing and re-pairing the watch with my iPhone.
Resetting both the iPhone and Watch.
Verifying background modes and capabilities are correctly set for the watchOS app.
Xcode version: 15
iOS version: 17
watchOS version: 8.8.1
Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution to get around it? Any insights would be greatly appreciated

Hi David Pasztor sir, are you here?
